# Firebase database backgroundservice error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app which is used to place product requests. More of like a shopping app. The user will get offers when the admin posts one.
I used firebase and created a root called `offers` and the offers are added as child under the offers node.
[image: Database structure of offers node]

i have created a firebasebackground listener service and added onChildEventListener. When ever a new offer is posted the user is notified with the offer.

```
Firebasebackgroundservice.java:
public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends Service {

    private DatabaseReference f;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
    private TinyDB database;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId) {
        super.onCreate();
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        database=new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
        f= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference foff=f.child("offers");

        foff.limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ArrayList<String>offarray=new ArrayList<String>();
                offarray=database.getListString("offdata");
                if(!offarray.contains(dataSnapshot.getKey())){
                    offarray.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    database.putListString("offdata",offarray);
                    Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    String title=newPost.get("title").toString();
                    String code=newPost.get("code").toString();
                    postNotif(title,code);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //Order updates
        String uname=database.getString("uname");
        final DatabaseReference fupd=f.child("users").child(uname).child("notif");
        fupd.limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ArrayList<String>offarray=new ArrayList<String>();
                offarray=database.getListString("updata");
                if(!offarray.contains(dataSnapshot.getKey())){
                    offarray.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    database.putListString("updata",offarray);
                    Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    String title=newPost.get("title").toString();
                    String code=newPost.get("code").toString();
                    updateNotif(title,code);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void postNotif(String title,String descp) {
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        try {
            int smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_card;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CharSequence contentTitle = title;
            CharSequence contentText = descp;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,OfferActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setWhen(when)
                    .setContentText(contentText)
                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(contentTitle)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(alarmSound);
            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Notification Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void updateNotif(String title,String descp) {
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        try {
            int smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_file_upload;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CharSequence contentTitle = title;
            CharSequence contentText = descp;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,Notifications.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setWhen(when)
                    .setContentText(contentText)
                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(contentTitle)
                    .setLargeIcon(icon)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(alarmSound);
            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Notification Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        startService(new Intent(this,FirebaseBackgroundService.class));
    }

}
```

The app is working fine but I am facing two issues here:
1. When the service is started initially the notifications are shown. But at times the service is being `killed` by the OS. And when the service is restarted the notifications are not shown. The service is being killed and is not restarted for a long time.
2. The `childAddedListener` is not called after the service `resumes` and hence the notifications are also not shown

The app works perfectly fine on first start of service. once the service is killed the notifications are not shown and the `childaddedlistener` is not working

Please help me with this. I searched a lot for `firebasebackgroundservice` but ended up with this. Thank you.

Comment: By "notified" do you mean a push notification when the app is in the background?

Comment: Yes. When the child is added under offers the background service should show notification.

Comment: Have you considered using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for your push notifications?

Comment: It is indeed expected behavior that database changes are only synchronized to the client when the service is active. In order to prolong battery life, the OS may kill such long-running services. The solution is (as Rohan said) to use a service like FCM to either deliver background data or (more involved, but more scalable) to wake up the service when it needs to synchronize data. See [my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210186/handling-keepsynced-while-on-background-on-android-and-with-fcm/42210878#42210878).